# Using object in views in Kohana 3.0

Tags: kohana-3

I am upgrading a project from [Kohana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohana) 2 to Kohana 3.

In the Kohana 2 version, in the view file, it is written:

```
if ($this->uri->segment('page'))
{
    if ($this->uri->segment(5))
    {
```

In Kohana 3, I changed this to

```
if ($this->request->param('page'))
{
    if ($this->request->param('param5'))
    {
```

but it's giving the following error message.

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Using $this when not in object context

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Request::current()->param();`. Refer to *[Upgrading from 2.x](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/upgrading#view-library)* for further details.